# Unity - One Button for all Clone Objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Hallo**,

I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMROaOQs7z8&t=7s

Selecting cars in the game using the Instantiate () function changes the prefabricated cars and I want to control them (throttle, brake, etc.) with using the UI buttons

I have a problem that the button does not find the event trigger (pointerDown, pointerUp) on newly created cloned objects, because the prefab is still changing

I have buttons and not keys (as in the video), the buttons do not find inputs to newly created objects.

I tried to do this using a script pinned to a button, with OnPointerEnter () and OnPointerExit () but it doesn't work, how should I do it? I will be grateful for any answer, thanks.

unity version 2019.4.14f1

```
public class GasButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CarController controller;

    private void Update()
    {
        controller = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<CarController>();
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        controller.GasPressed();
        Debug.Log("Gas Pressed");
    }
    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        controller.GasReleased();
        Debug.Log("Gas Released");

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnPointerEnter` and `OnPointerExit` should implement the `IPointerEnterHandler` and `IPointerExitHandler`.

To do this append interface in the monobehavior like this.

```
public class GasButton : MonoBehaviour,IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    public CarController controller;

    private void Update()
    {
        controller = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<CarController>();
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        controller.GasPressed();
        Debug.Log("Gas Pressed");
    }
    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        controller.GasReleased();
        Debug.Log("Gas Released");

    }
```

Comment: This solved my problem, Thank you very much!